# FME spatial join by PointOnAreaOverlayer transformer rejects Invalid Polygon Geometry Type

Tags: geometry, fme-form, spatial-join

I would like to perform a spatial join of points and polygons in FME Workbench by PointOnAreaOverlayer transformer. The result should be a country polygons with additional attributes from points. I have a workspace:

[image]

What I have in rejected features, in attribute table column fme_rejection_code: Invalid Polygon Geometry Type:

[image]

Do you know how can I repair or change the Invalid Polygon Geometry Type features? I have tried GeometryValidator transformer - without results - all areas were rejected in PointOnAreaOverlayer transformer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rejected features are probably aggregates (collections).

You can use a DeAggregator to explode the collections.

```
Aggregates can either be deaggregated before processing or rejected.
```

Source: http://docs.safe.com/fme/2019.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/pointonareaoverlayer.htm

Comment: Right answer! I had to deaggregate and later aggregate the polygons.

Answer (score 0):

[@nielsgerrits](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/63260/nielsgerrits) answer led me to the solution. In PointOnAreaOverlayer transformer I have to deaggregate features, and later aggregate them by aggregator transformer.

[image]